# Nuxt.js only loading static folder js on first load

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm very new to Nuxt.js so I imagine this will be an obvious one but I've searched and searched and I'm still scratching my head.

I have started by using this tutorial https://css-tricks.com/simple-server-side-rendering-routing-page-transitions-nuxt-js/ and it seems to be working.

I want to add some custom .js so I can add simple interactions, for instance toggle classes.

I have put jquery-2.1.4.min.js and my custom main.js in the static folder and linked in the config file and my toggle class works on first page load although if I navigate away from the index page and back again it doesn't work.

I guess It's something to do with SSR, is there a way I can get this to work on every page and when navigating back and forth. At some point, I will want to add plugins and I've tried adding these files to the plugin folder but again only worked on first page load.

Thanks for your help,

```
module.exports = {
 css: [
   '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
  ],
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' },
      { src: '/js/main.js' }
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what is not working.  And why u even need jquery? You dont need jquery to toggle classes or anything like this if you using  nuxt and vue.

Comment: @Aldarund you haven't answered the question. Problems loading js files from static folder are here. They sometimes stop working when you hit the nuxt router.

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo you shouldnt mix not vue static js with nuxt, it lead to mess. Unless its just some external widgets like stats, chat etc